# Solving a PDE possibly with method of characteristics or other methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a PDE $$(x-y^{2}) u_{x} + u_{y} = 0$$ I've tried to use method of characteristics. But I've failed to do so. It was because of the term $x-y^{2}$; I don't know how to integrate this on the characteristic line. Should I try another method than method of chracteristic? Or is there a clever trick for this?

Related equatons:
$dx/ds = x-y^{2}$, $dy/ds = 1$, $du/ds = 0$.

Comment: If you integrate the $dy/ds=1$ and obtain $y=s$ then $dx/ds = x-s^2$ which is integrable by partial fractions.

Comment: ah I think it becomes $dx/ds = x-s^2$...

Comment: strike the partial fractions.

Comment: hm.. I'm not sure how that really works.. since $s$ is not a constant

Comment: Integrating factor method. Look at it as $dx/ds-x=-s^2$.

Comment: Okay I know how to do integrating factor method using exponential. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Ah.. May I ask you one more question? The guy below assumed $y =s$ but shouldn't it be $y = s + y_{0}$? If I use the latter, the calculation becomes much complex. How should I resolve it?

Comment: $y=s+y_0$ gives you exactly the same curves, just shifted in $s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving your "related equations" should give you the solutions: $u$ is constant on the curves $y = s$, $x = 2+2 s+s^2+ c \exp(s)$, i.e. $u = F((x - 2 - 2 y - y^2) \exp(-y))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how did you get the $x$ part?

Comment: Ah.. just one short question. Is it okay to use $y=s$ rather than $y=y_{0} +s$ because if I use the latter, the problem gets much harder...